# Invoice value not defined in IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm starting to IPN posts that do not have the invoice number. This is happening randomly. I have doubled checked the code and the URL and have verified that I am passing a value for invoice.
&invoice=123456

This started happening more often this year and I'm not able to track down the error. I'm not able to reproduce this.

Comment: Need to see actual samples of the request that generated a payment, which includes the invoice value, and also the IPN data that resulted from that same transaction.

Comment: Here is the the request URL.
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=paypal%40xxxx.com&email=xxxx%40gmail.com&amount=88.95&image_url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.xxxx.com%2fimages%2flogo.gif&item_name=xxxx+xxxx+Order%23+110781&invoice=110781&return=https%3a%2f%2fwww.xxxxxx.com%2fModules%2fStore%2fCheckout.aspx%3fPayPal%3dSuccess&cancel_return=https%3a%2f%2fwww.xxxxxx.com%2fModules%2fStore%2fCheckout.aspx%3fPayPal%3dCancel

Comment: Here is the response

mc_gross=88.95&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=XENNKKFMWQJEU&tax=0.00&address_street=10515 xxxxx Apt xxx&payment_date=12:09:46 Mar 09, 2015 PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=xxxxx&first_name=xxxx&mc_fee=2.88&address_country_code=US&address_name=xxxxxx&notify_version=3.8&custom=&payer_status=verified&business=paypal@xxxxx.com&address_country=

Comment: United States&address_city=xxxxx&quantity=1&verify_sign=Az9Xd1arTA5cZDl3CswiCti0qSA.AmEcpeiGXwtk8kyu32ZokN5xJ16p&payer_email=xxxxx@GMAIL.COM&txn_id=1Y096731BR429014N&payment_type=instant&last_name=xxxxx&address_state=VA&receiver_email=paypal@xxxxx&payment_fee=2.88&receiver_id=Q6T6WMNUD7N3A&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=xxxxxxx Order&mc_currency=USD&item_number=&residence_country=US&handling_amount=0.00&transaction_subject=xxxxx&payment_gross=88.95&shipping=0.00&ipn_track_id=16b3a6f0b2dcc

Comment: And what about the IPN you got back from that?

Comment: I posted the ipn response. I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: If you're certain that is the matching IPN that resulted from that payment URL then you'll need to submit these details to [PayPal MTS](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=paypal%40xxxx.com&email=xxxx%40gmail.com&amount=88.95&image_url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.xxxx.com%2fimages%2flogo.gif&item_name=xxxx+xxxx+Order%23+110781&invoice=110781&return=https%3a%2f%2fwww.xxxxxx.com%2fModules%2fStore%2fCheckout.aspx%3fPayPal%3dSuccess&cancel_return=https%3a%2f%2fwww.xxxxxx.com%2fModules%2fStore%2fCheckout.aspx%3fPayPal%3dCancel) so they can look into a bug.

Comment: I use IPN heavily with invoice IDs, though, and I haven't had that problem, so I'm still kinda thinking somehow that request isn't matching up with the IPN..??

Comment: Yes, I'm certain. I pulled the request and response from the logs.
I did email PayPal and they said they could not reproduce it and the the request was providing the correct response. 
They said to add paymentaction=sale to the querystring. Do you have that?

This is happening around once a week now. We do at least 800 PayPal orders per month.

Comment: I do run most of my transactions as Sale, yes.  Are you running as Auth or Order?